# Use ProjectName when building an entire solution with MSBuild

Tags: build, msbuild, solution

Rather than building to the default folder structure, which is like

```
Solution.sln
Project1
    bin    <- project 1 output
    obj    <- project 1 intermediate output
Project2
    bin    <- project 2 output
    obj    <- project 2 intermediate output
```

I instead want to build it like

```
Solution.sln
bin    <- project 1 AND 2 output
obj
    Project1   <- project 1 intermediate output
    Project2   <- project 2 intermediate output
```

I can do

```
msbuild "/p:OutputPath=../bin" "/p:IntermediateOutputPath=../obj/" Test123.sln
```

However, using `"/p:IntermediateOutputPath=../obj/$(ProjectName)/"` does not work. Instead of creating a folder for each project, it creates one folder literally called `$(ProjectName)` (I've read that most, but not all of these macros are actually a Visual Studio thing, rather than MSBuild magic).

How can I use a project-specific value (such as `ProjectName`) in a property value (such as `IntermediateOutputPath`) when building?

(Some background information:

Having one `bin` folder on the solution level saves unnecessary copying of output files, which quickly amass over 100 MB in large solutions. Furthermore, it keeps the source folders clean so they can be read-only.

I still want separate `obj` folders though, because who knows what goes in there - might be the same file names for different projects.)

Comment: I doubt you can do this directly from the command line without modifying the project files. However your actual question isn't clear: do you only want that single bin directory for command line builds? Or always? wrt *I've read that most, but not all of these macros are actually a Visual Studio thing rather than msbuild magic*: no idea where you got that, but that is not at all the case. Your problem here seems to be `$(ProjectName)` is passed as a literal string and doesn't get interpreted by msbuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.Common.targets,71) property of the [Microsoft.Common.targets](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.Common.targets,fc4f41473ee2f8f2) file. It's allowing injecting custom targets into projects and performs some actions.

---

The entry point of the build process is `Make.targets`:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"; DefaultTargets="EntryMSBuild">

    <ItemGroup>
        <Project Include="**\*.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="EntryMSBuild">

        <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>
        <Message Text="    Rebuild    " Importance="high"/>
        <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>

        <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="rebuild" Properties="CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets=$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Setting.targets"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

---

In `Setting.targets` defined `IntermediateOutputPath` and `OutputPath` for each projects:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>..\Global\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputPath>..\Global\bin\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

- IntermediateOutputPath - depend on [$(MSBuildProjectName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties);
- OutputPath - common for all projects.

---

As a result, you get the desired structure:

```
Solution.sln
bin    <- project 1 AND 2 output
obj
    Project1   <- project 1 intermediate output
    Project2   <- project 2 intermediate output
```

---

Tested on solution with two projects under `.net46` and `.netstandard2.0`. `MSBuild` 15.6.82.30579

---

You don’t need store custom targets under `C:\Program Files[(x86)]\microsoft visual studio\2017\xxx\msbuild\15.0` or any predefined path. You override `CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets` property that already defined in `Microsoft.Common.targets` and injected in the project by default.

From `Microsoft.Common.targets` comment:

> This file defines the steps in the standard build process for .NET
> projects. It contains all the steps that are common among the
> different .NET languages, such as Visual Basic, and Visual C#.

Comment: Looks promising, but if I understand this (and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246015/copy-built-assemblies-including-pdb-config-and-xml-comment-files-to-folder-p)) correctly, I need to put the custom targets under `c:\program files[ (x86)]\microsoft visual studio\2017\xxx\msbuild\15.0\`, which means that everyone who wants to build the solution needs write access in that folder, and also that it affects all projects built on the machine. Is that correct? Is there a way to do this without changing anything in the msbuild installation folder?

Comment: You can find many useful information about this in [Supplement to Inside the Microsoft Build Engine](https://books.google.ru/books?id=l7hCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=From+the+sample+in+Chapter+8,+we+simply+placed+the+file&source=bl&ots=jB1lB6MIQn&sig=IGMdPcM-Cvr10CmLtkTGKTjbGoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz9-nFwM7aAhUM3SwKHQPBCPcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=From%20the%20sample%20in%20Chapter%208%2C%20we%20simply%20placed%20the%20file&f=false) book on page 25.

Comment: Got it to work. My mistake was that the path you set the property to apparently must be absolute, like `msbuild "/p:CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets=d:\dev\...\Setting.targets" Solution123.sln`